# Creating buffer around points belonging to object using lidR

Tags: buffer, las, lidr, point-cloud

I would like to create a 3D buffer around powerlines inside a LAS file that contains forest and power lines in lidR (R package). If I would manually delineate the line features and export to an individual file,

How do I create a buffer around all points in that file?

I am thinking of something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a shapefile with lines you can buffer the lines and clip the polygons

```r
library(lidR)
library(sf)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
ctg = readLAScatalog(LASfile)

# read a shapefile (here I'm making one manually)
m1 = matrix(c(684800, 685000, 5017800, 5018000), ncol = 2)
m2 = matrix(c(684900, 685000, 5017900, 5017900), ncol = 2)
powerline1 = st_linestring(m1)
powerline2 = st_linestring(m2)
powerlines = st_sfc(powerline1, powerline2)
powerlines = st_sf(powerlines)
st_crs(powerlines) = st_crs(ctg)

# Buffer the lines
buffer = st_buffer(powerlines, 10, endCapStyle = "SQUARE")

# Some plot
plot(ctg)
plot(powerlines, add = T)
plot(buffer, add = T, lty = 3, col = "NA")
```

[image]

```r
# Extract the polygons and stream them into output files
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0(tempdir(), "/powerline_{ID}")
newctg = clip_roi(ctg, buffer)

# plot the new ctg
plot(newctg)
```

[image]

```r
# The new file are in
newctg$filename
#> [1] "/tmp/Rtmp39NXdd/powerline_1.las" "/tmp/Rtmp39NXdd/powerline_2.las"
```